# Trying to replace my boost::asio::read with boost::asio::async_read

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

So, the code I started with and which works (with important caveats below)

```
int reply_length = boost::asio::read(*m_socketptr, boost::asio::buffer((char*)reply, 6));
```

This works, I get the header which I then decode and follow up with another read which gets me my message and then I loop back to the top and read another header.  This pegs my CPU at 100% so I want to replace the header read above with something like the following:

```
m_socketptr->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_data, 6), boost::bind(&CSListener::handleRead, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

or

```
boost::asio::async_read(*m_socketptr, boost::asio::buffer(m_data, 6), boost::bind(&CSListener::handleRead, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Either way I code it, the handleRead method is not ever getting called.  Help!?

TIA

Comment: Could you post more code? It would help to see how you use the io_service and how you handle the additional thread.

Comment: Thanks nabulke, it was misuse of io_service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you have created an `io_service` somewhere in your code?  You need to call its [`io_service.run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run.html) or [`io_service.run_one()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run_one.html) to make it work.  If you need it to be async, then `run_one()` is you man; put a call to it in you app's/thread's main loop.

Comment: yes, I have an io_service in the main thread.  I use it to create a shared_ptr to a boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket which I pass to the thread that reads from it.

Comment: @shaz but do you call the `run`or `run_one` functions?  Those are the ones that do all the work.